# How to Update Environment Variables in bedrock installation while in ubuntu?

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, roots-toolkit

I'm trying to install bedrock wordpress stack on ubuntu, but i don't know how to update the environment variables after    cp .env.example .env ? so i can't find the file containing this:

```
DB_NAME - Database name
DB_USER - Database user
DB_PASSWORD - Database password
DB_HOST - Database host
WP_ENV - Set to environment (development, staging, production)
WP_HOME - Full URL to WordPress home (http://example.com)
WP_SITEURL - Full URL to WordPress including subdirectory (http://example.com/wp)
```

so .. how to do that on ubuntu ?